# C# AttributeUsage for Specific Class

Tags: c#, attributes, attributeusage

Is it possible to have something like AttributeUsage to restrict the use of an attribute to a **specific** class (not just AttributeTargets.Class - that would be any class)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  There is nothing in the framework that would do this.

However, the code that **uses** the attribute in question could always check to make sure that the class's type is the specific class (or one of its subclasses).

Attributes, by themselves, do nothing - so this should have the same effect.

Answer (score 14):

One way to accomplish this, if you have access to the specific class, is detailed by Marc Gravel here: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/06/restricting-attribute-usage.html.  Basically you implement the attribute as a protected class of the specific type.  Then it can only be used by that type.

Answer (score 0):

Make all data in the Attribute accessible only by a public static method which takes the class you want in question and checks to see if it has the given attribute.